# How can I find Windows 7 drivers for this laptop?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

I recently bought a laptop, Asus ux303ub. https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/

I installed Windows 7 on it, however almost nothing works, including usb ports, wifi chip etc.. Therefore I have no Internet connection and Windows 7 can not update itself.

I boot with a ubuntu usb and connect to the Internet and I can download drivers and copy it to the harddrive where Windows 7 is installed.

I want to get either the USB ports or the wireless chipset working, but what should I install for this particular computer? Once I get connected to the Internet I am hoping everything will be easier.

So what drivers should I download for this computer to get wifi or usb ports working with Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

This laptop is a using the Intel Skylake architecture, which is supported from Windows 10 only.

You may try to find drivers for older versions of Windows by searching on the website of each component maker.

For the Intel chipset that handle a lot of functionalities, you can try the following driver :
https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop/k1chp11us17.exe

Answer (score -1):

[Drivers for 7x64 WiFi](http://filehippo.com/download_intel_pro_wireless_win7_64/)

The trick to getting any driver for any laptop is to check on the official site what specific components it has, under any version of OS the manufacturer is providing drivers for. Then you just search for that component driver for the OS version you need.

In your case, the notebook uses an Intel wireless adapter.

Comment: Wow. That link looks trustworthy...

Comment: I already tried this and I am getting a message saying: "This computer does not need the minimum requirements for installing the software.."

Answer (score -1):

You should find drivers at manufacturer's website for your laptop's model. You should install following drivers in this order

1. Chipset drivers
2. USB drivers
3. Display/VGA drivers (If you facing problems like high brightness or flickering screen)
4. LAN drivers (Ethernet)
5. Wireless drivers (Wifi and bluetooth)

Comment: -1 Why would you *not* install the VGA drivers?

Comment: Some manufacturer's put graphics drivers under the name of VGA, although they are not of VGA ports. Thats why, I just suggested to look for Display/VGA drivers.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I'm saying you would want to install display drivers even if you aren't' having brightness or flickering problems.